# AngularJS update var in DOM referenced through function through controller

Tags: angularjs, variables

How can I update the value of a variable that's sent to a function, from within that same function?

HTML:

```
Message is: {{ msg }}
<button ng-click="updateVar(msg)">Update</button>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.msg = 'Init';

$scope.updateVar = function(varToUpdate) {
    varToUpdate = 'Var was updated!';
};
```

I can't do `$scope.msg = 'Var was updated!';`, since in the function I'm writing, I have many variables to potentially update, and I don't want to write different cases for every single variable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateVar(msg)` passes the **value** of `$scope.msg` to the function.

You want to pass the variable **name** (or rather, the $scope property name): `updateVar('msg')`

And your function can then use the variable name to modify its value:

```
$scope.updateVar = function(varToUpdate) {
    $scope[varToUpdate] = 'Var was updated!';
};
```

Comment: It works very well, thank you! It doesn't work with arrays though. Do you know of a way? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51757108/angularjs-update-array-var-and-non-array-var-whose-names-were-obtained-by-string