# AngularJS update array var and non-array var whose names were obtained by string

Tags: arrays, angularjs, variables

I'm trying to update different variables that are obtained as strings. Some are arrays, and some are not. For these values to be updated by the same function, I'd need for them to be obtained by a string. The following code only works with non-array variables.

HTML:

```
Message is: {{ message }}
<button ng-click="updateVar('message')">Update</button>
<br>
Message in array is: {{ messages.welcome }}
<button ng-click="updateVar('messages.welcome')">Update</button>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.message = 'Simple message';

$scope.messages = {
    welcome: 'Message in array'
};

$scope.updateVar = function(varToUpdate) {
    $scope[varToUpdate] = 'Var was updated!';
};
```

How can I make this work with arrays?

Thank you!

Comment: In JavaScript collections that use curley brackets (`'{'`,`'}'`) are called "objects". Collections that use squares (`'['`,`']'`) are called arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the displayed variable as a parameter:

```
Message is: {{ message }}
<button ng-click="updateVar(message)">Update</button>
<p>
Message in array is: {{ messages.welcome }}
<button ng-click="updateVar(messages.welcome)">Update</button>
```

& in your js file:

```
$scope.message = 'Simple message';

$scope.messages = {
    welcome: 'Message in array'
};

$scope.updateVar = function(varToUpdate) {
     $scope[varToUpdate] = 'Var was updated!';
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work, since only the value is passed, not the actual property. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756366/angularjs-update-var-in-dom-referenced-through-function-through-controller/51756417#51756417

Comment: @MarcusEdensky but that's what you want to achieve isn't it?

Comment: No, what I need to achieve is to be able to not only read the value, but to update that property from within the funcion, only using the name of the variable obtained as a string.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't  $scope.varToUpdate  in the second case contains {
        welcome: 'Message in array'
    } ? If not please write the output you want to achieve. I think your problem is an XY one

Comment: It does, but only the value. If I try to modify it with `varToUpdate = 'Var is updated!';`, this will only be valid within the function (when I for example do one alert before, and one after), but doesn't affect the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

In JavaScript, collections that use curly brackets (`'{'`,`'}'`) are called [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics). Collections that use squares (`'['`,`']'`) are called [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps/Arrays).

To update a property of an object, simply use an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) in the `ng-click` directive:

```
<input ng-model="message" />
<button ng-click="messages.welcome = message">Update object</button>
```

On each click of the <kbd>Update object</kbd> button, the `welcome` property of the `messages` object will be updated with the current value of the `message` input.

### The DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope) {
   $scope.message="Sample message";
   $scope.messages={welcome: "Not updated"};
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input ng-model="message" />
  <br>
  Message is: {{ message }} 
  <br>
  Message in object is: {{ messages.welcome }}
  <br> 
  <button ng-click="messages.welcome = message">Update object</button>
</body>
```

Comment: The question wasn't about assigning a value to a variable through the click of a button. It's about how to assign a value to a variable (or a variable inside an object) from within a function, with only the name of the variable being sent to the function as a string. Similar to this question, but also with variables in objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51756366/angularjs-update-var-in-dom-referenced-through-function-through-controller/51756417#51756417

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution!

In the end I had to explode any dots '.' from the string, and then treat the value differently depending on if it is in an array or not.

HTML:

```
Message is: {{ message }}
<button ng-click="updateVarByString('message', 'New string')">Update</button>
<br>
Message in array is: {{ messages.welcome }}
<button ng-click="updateVarByString('messages.welcome', 'New string')">Update</button>
```

AngularJS:

```
$scope.message = 'Simple message';

$scope.messages = {
    welcome: 'Message in array'
};

//Update a var or an array element, fetching it only by its name as a string
$scope.updateVarByString = function(varName, newVal) {
    var varNameExploded = varName.split('.');

    if (varNameExploded.length == 1) {
        $scope[varNameExploded[0]] = newVal;
    } else if (varNameExploded.length == 2) {
        $scope[varNameExploded[0]][varNameExploded[1]] = newVal;
    }
};
```